# OkHttpClient.clone() where is it documented? How to use?

Tags: android, okhttp

Could you point to some documentation or code where I can see what `OkhttpClient.clone()` does? I have only found javadoc saying that it creates a shallow copy. What does it mean? Where is the cloning in code? `OkHttpClient` class doesn't overwrite `clone()` method although it implements `Cloneable` interface. What's the purpose of it?

Comment: Interceptors lists are now deep-copied by `OkHttpClient.clone()`. Previously clones shared interceptors, which made it difficult to customize the interceptors on a request-by-request basis.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about `Object.clone()` which exists in all classes in Java because they are all extending `Object` class.

This method could create the copy of some object instance but only if class of this object implements interface  `Cloneable`. In case of `OkHttpClient` you can use it for pretty same thing.

Some more information you can find here
https://www.javatpoint.com/object-cloning

Comment: Interface `Cloneable` has no methods. That's a special kind of interfaces which only marks class as suitable for some functionality. Method `clone()` is `protected` method of class `Object` and if you want to expose it you should create your own public method which will calls the protected one from `Object`.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

Comment: That's all is known for me. But OkHttpClient implements the interface, but does not overwrite the clone() method. Is that an intended behavior or an error? What does the clone is made of in such cases in Java?

Comment: @JesseWilson in what way will it be fixed? Removed clonable() interface, or implemented?